# Should I set up a server or use Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux

I'm currently using ExpressJS server with PostgreSQL database. I'm fine with it, I like to use it, but I had read about Firebase, and watched a course, and I don't have any reason not to switch to it. Why doesn't everybody use Firebase? In which use cases is it worth to stay with manually setting up server, and database, fetch in the frontend etc?

What I need to fill a database with users, the users with two arrays, and arrays with objects, and to use an authentication for the login, then use the data with Redux, so it isn't too complicated. Is this a case where it is worth to switch to Firebase? And what's the case when it's not?

Comment: Somebody please tell me why downvoting...

Comment: The downvotes may have been a result of the voter believing this question to be too broad.

Comment: this is really a matter of opinion, not something that has a clear answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is soliciting opinions and while that not a bad thing, it's just not a good fit for this site. It is a good question though. But. You should really start going though the documentation a bit more fully. Firebase is not a local server. They host the server and provide the services. You make the front end UI to connect their server. Also there's a very good section in the documentation about [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/).

Answer (score 5):

> Why not everybody use Firebase?

- Firebase offers a NoSql database, which some people prefer to do their own database instead of working with this kind of databases.

> In which use cases is it worth to stay with manually setting up
>   server, and database, fetch in the frontend etc.?

- In my opinion is too arbitrary, because if you have already set up a database and it's working I don't see why you need to move, it's true that Firebase is really really structured and it's really nice to work with, easy and scalable, but I don't see the reason of moving if you have already a working database for your app

> What i need to fill a database with users, the users with two arrays,
>   and arrays with objects, and to use an authentication for the login,
>   then use the data with redux, so it isn't too complicated.

- It's not that hard, Firebase works with Json, so structuring what you want will take just some Json Objects and some Json Arrays, Firebase comes with Google sign in, your own custom email and password sign in, Facebook and twitter sign in, GitHub and phone auth

> Is this a case where it is worth to switch to Firebase?

- If you feel comfortable to switch on it will be a big improvement in the manage of your app, since firebase offers you a lot of tools to work with, to work with your users, with ads , statics, Crashlytics and a lot of cool features under the same dome.

One of the coolest features of Firebase is functions, and it's done with JavaScript, take a look at it here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/